# How to build Android APK via Gitlab CI/CD and Docker?

Tags: android, docker, gradle, gitlab, continuous-integration

I have installed Gitlab-Runner and configured it with **shell** executor on my macOS **locally**.

I have the following .yaml

```yaml
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/qfunz/Library/Android/sdk
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/qfunz/Library/Android/sdk
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

create common folder to store build:
  stage: build
  needs: []
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - mkdir popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa


get debug apk build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:assembleGooglePlayDebug
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/googlePlay/debug/*.apk ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa

get release apk build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:assembleGooglePlayRelease
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/googlePlay/release/*.apk ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa

get release aab build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - shell
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:bundleGooglePlayRelease
    - mv app/build/outputs/bundle/googlePlayRelease/*.aab ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa

get one folder build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - shell
  needs: [get debug apk build, get release apk build, get release aab build]
  script:
    - echo "DONE!!!!!!!!"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa
```

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oYGM.jpg) and works well and can be done with ~ 3 minutes

But it was configured locally on my macOS with my personal Android SDK so it can't be independent. So I want to change **shell** executor to **docker**

What I've tried?

0. I've created one more Gitlab-Runner and configured it like this:

```
concurrent = 10
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker"
  url = "https://MYURL/"
  token = "MYTOKEN"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

1. I've created my Dockerfile

```sh
FROM jangrewe/gitlab-ci-android

USER root

WORKDIR proj/

COPY . .

ENV SDK_URL="https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-mac-8512546_latest.zip" \
    ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk" 

RUN mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME" .android \
    && cd "$ANDROID_HOME" \
    && mkdir cmdline-tools \
    && cd cmdline-tools \
    && curl -o sdk.zip $SDK_URL \
    && unzip sdk.zip \
    && rm sdk.zip \
    && mv ./cmdline-tools ./latest \
    && mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true \
    && echo "24333f8a63b6825ea9c5514f83c2829b004d1fee" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license" \
    && cd latest \
    && cd bin \
    && ./sdkmanager --update \
    && yes | ./sdkmanager "build-tools;30.0.3" \
    "platforms;android-30" \
    "platform-tools"
```

2. I've built this with **docker build** and push it to Gitlab Container Registry, so I can use it like an image
3. I've change my .yaml to

```yaml
default:                                                  <-----------
  image: pushed_image_from_conteiner_registry             <-----------

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle
  - export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk            <-----------
  - export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/android-sdk        <-----------
  - chmod +x ./gradlew

stages:
  - build

create common folder to store build:
  stage: build
  needs: []
  tags:
    - docker                          <-----------
  script:
    - mkdir popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa


get debug apk build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - docker                          <-----------
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:assembleGooglePlayDebug
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/googlePlay/debug/*.apk ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa

get release apk build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - docker                          <-----------
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:assembleGooglePlayRelease
    - mv app/build/outputs/apk/googlePlay/release/*.apk ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa

get release aab build:
  stage: build
  needs: [create common folder to store build]
  tags:
    - docker                          <-----------
  script:
    - ./gradlew app:bundleGooglePlayRelease
    - mv app/build/outputs/bundle/googlePlayRelease/*.aab ./popa
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa

get one folder build:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - docker                          <-----------
  needs: [get debug apk build, get release apk build, get release aab build]
  script:
    - echo "DONE!!!!!!!!"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./popa
```

(I've marked lines which have changed)

And when I run my pipeline, 2/3 tasks just stuck on this stage:

```
Welcome to Gradle 7.4.2!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Aggregated test and JaCoCo reports
 - Marking additional test source directories as tests in IntelliJ
 - Support for Adoptium JDKs in Java toolchains
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/release-notes.html
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
```

What should I change in my code for **shell** executor (which works well) to run it with docker executor?

P.S. give me +10 rep so I could attach any image you want to specify my problem